# Value Insert error in LINQ/C# for Column identity

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The Below code i used.
SQL table name: tbl_Student
Columns : student_id (identity), Firstname, Lastname, Location, Email.

When i submit the below code. The following error will occur. I am new to this concept. I don't know how to manage the identity column. pls help.

> Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on
>   'Table(tbl_Student)' because it has no primary key in c#

```
        tbl_Student ts = new tbl_Student();
        ts.Firstname = textBox1.Text;
        ts.Lastname = textBox2.Text;
        ts.Location = textBox3.Text;
        ts.Email = textBox4.Text;
        db.tbl_Students.InsertOnSubmit(ts);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: In SSMS right click the table and select Design, highlight `student_id` and click the little icon that looks like a key. Save, and regenerate the models.

Comment: Already i added the primary key to that colomn. But still it return error

Comment: Save, and *regenerate the models.*

Comment: ya thanks alot. I forgot that..

Answer (score 1):

As specified :

`Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on a table because it has no primary key in c#`

You will either need to try executing the command yourself ( via `ExecuteCommand`), or better yet - **modify your tables to have a key**, which is highly recommended.

*Note: As I specified in the comments below, after adding the key, regeneration of the models is needed.*

**Example for executing a query yourself:**

```
db.ExecuteQuery<Studnet>("INSERT INTO tbl_Student VALUES(Firstname ,LastName, Location, Email)");
```

Comment: I used executecommand also for set on/off identity property before & after insertion query but it return same error.

Comment: so you've added a key and the problem persists? did you regenerate your models?

Comment: Error recovered. I forgot to regenerate the models after modifying in table. Anyway thank u so much.

Comment: please consider [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Future Stackoverflow users might benefit from your question. if no answer suited you, you can post your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a primary key in the database table when you generated the Linq to SQL classes through the designer? Just to make sure, regenerate these classes through the designer.

Comment: I forgot to regenerate the models after modifying in table. Anyway thank u so much